# Angular bootstrap Modal component not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog

I am trying to add Modals from bootstrap for angular, but it seems like it's not working : https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples

I copy/pasted the last modal 'Global configuration of modals'

Of course I imported it and placed it in my `declarations` variables + in the constructor.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: oh indeed my fault i got an error in console : `No component factory found for NgbModalBackdrop. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?`

Answer (score 0):

Yep. This is a very common issue when adding modals, whether it's bootstrap or the Material library modals.

Take a look at their example [here](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=app/modal-component.ts). You'll notice they added `entryComponents: [NgbdModalContent]`. Just make sure you do that as well in your code.

Specifically, do it inside the module file.

Comment: I added `entryComponents: [
      NgbModalBackdrop
  ]` to my module.ts but `ERROR in NgbModalBackdrop cannot be used as an entry component.`

Answer (score 0):

Adding NgbModule.forRoot() in my imports solves the problem